# Two Columns into one, no UNION

Tags: sql, select

I have got a table like this:

```
id | start date | end date |
1  | 1.1.2018   | 2.1.2018 |
2  | 1.1.2018   |          |
```

how is it possible to combine two it to:

```
id | start date | end date |
1  |1.1.2018    |          |
1  |            |2.1.2018  |
2  | 1.1.2018   |          |
```

any ideas?

tnx

Comment: Hint:  `UNION ALL`.

Comment: Why not `UNION`?

Comment: need a seperated row for each start or end date, even if ID match :)

Comment: The sample data has no duplicate id/dates. Anyway, do a UNION ALL.

Answer (score 2):

Simply `UNION ALL` non-null start dates and non-null end dates, in separate columns.

```
select id, start_date, null as end_date
from tablename
where start_date is not null
union all
select id, null, end_date
from tablename
where end_date is not null
```

If you want a specific order, follow @TheImpaler's suggestion and add an `ORDER BY` clause at the end:

```
order by id, coalesce(start_date, end_date)
```

Where `coalesce(start_date, end_date)` means the non-null value is chosen.

Comment: Maybe "order by id"?

Comment: Many thanks guys, will be back in my office in wednesday but it seems promising